# Why there is some inhomogeneous term in the PDE of fixed income

Tags: fixed-income, swaps, black-scholes-pde

We consider one factor driving model of fixed income product say short-term interest $r(t)=\lim\limits_{T\rightarrow t} R(t,T),$  $R(t,T)$ is yield i.e 
$$B(t,T)e^{(T-t)R(t,T)} = 1$$ Then we see several PDE of contingent claim

`Zero-coupon bond` $B(t,T)$
$$\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t} + LB -r(t)B = 0$$
here $L$ is the differential operator in Feynman-Kac equation.

`Swap of fixed rate` $r^*$
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t} + LV -r(t)V + (r - r^*) = 0$$

`Caplet at rate` $r*$
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t} + LV -r(t)V + \min(r,r^*) = 0$$

`Floorlet at rate` $r*$
$$\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t} + LV -r(t)V + \max(r,r^*) = 0$$

Here $r = r(t)$
and $V(t,T,r(t))$ is the value of contingent claim which is the function of $t$ and $r$ e.g, for zero-coupon bond $V=B.$

I couldn't understand when the dynamic of $r(t)$ is given, why there are some inhomogeneous terms in the Black-Scholes equation? Can some one explain one of later three?

Comment: Can you please provide more background information? Where are these equations from? What is $V$ for each case? Is $r=r(t)$?

Comment: @Gordon please see the updated version, and the question is in Duffy's book `Finite Difference Methods in Financial Engineering` Page276

Comment: See my answer to your another question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula, it is the $f(X_r,r)$ in the formula. For the swap you receive $(r-r^*) dt$ (assume notional of 1) which translates into your $f$ (inhomogeneous term).

Comment: Conversely for a ZCB it is zero because you receive nothing (no cash flows) during the life of the ZCB.

Comment: Sorry, you mean we receive the cash flow continuously? What I have learnt is for each time interval $[T_i,T_{i+1}]$ we receive the money at $T_{i+1}.$ Is it the discrete case?

Comment: Hi @user26484. Thanks for your contribution, could please use the LaTeX formatting to make your comment clearer in the future? Thanks